# Transform a HTML using XSL with XSLT1.0 in Siebel?

Tags: html, xslt-1.0

I have a HTML like this below. I need to use XSLT 1.0 and remove the elements below a certain element in the following HTML based on the attribute value of a child element in one of the elements.

```html
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 </head>
 <body lang="EN-US">
  <div class="WordSection1">
   <p class="MsoNormal">
    <span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif">This is the document for ER Overview<o:p/>
    </span>
   </p>
   <p class="MsoNormal">
    <span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif">Test 1  <o:p/>
    </span>
   </p>  <p class="MsoNormal">
    <span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif">2<o:p/>
    </span>
   </p>  <p class="MsoNormal">
    <span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;background:yellow;mso-highlight:yellow">3</span>
    <span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif">
     <o:p/>
    </span>
   </p>  <p class="MsoNormal">
    <span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif">4<o:p/>
    </span>
   </p>  <p class="MsoNormal">
    <span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;background:lime;mso-highlight:lime">5</span>
    <span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif">
     <o:p/>
    </span>
   </p>  
   <p class="MsoNormal">
    <a name="_MailEndCompose">
     <span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif">
      <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
     </span>
    </a>
   </p>
   <span style="mso-bookmark:_MailEndCompose"/>
   <div>
    <div style="border:none;border-top:solid #E1E1E1 1.0pt;padding:3.0pt 0in 0in 0in">
     <p class="MsoNormal">
      <a name="_____replyseparator"/>
      <b>
       <span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif">From:</span>
      </b>
      <span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif"> AutoReply [mailto:reply@support.com]<br>
        <b>Sent:</b> Thursday, March 2, 2017 6:50 PM<br>
         <b>To:</b> Doe, John &lt;johndoe@support.com&gt;<br>
          <b>Subject:</b> This is a test for routing rules<o:p/>
         </span>
        </p>
       </div>
   </div>
       <p class="MsoNormal">
        <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
       </p>
       <table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="500" style="width:375.0pt">
        <tbody>
         <tr>
          <td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in">
           <p class="MsoNormal">The contents of the note are included below.<br>
             <br>If reply includes an attachment/image, please go Transaction Center to view the file.<br>
               <br>To add a Note, simply reply to the email.<br>Please do not edit the email subject.<br>
                  <br>The following note was posted by <a href="mailto:johndoe@support.com">johndoe@support.com</a>:<o:p/>
                  </p>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in">
           <p class="MsoNormal">_______________________________________________________________________<br>
             <br>
              <o:p/>
             </p><p class="MsoNormal">
              <span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif">Test 1</span>
              <o:p/>
             </p><p class="MsoNormal">
              <span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif">2</span>
              <o:p/>
             </p><p class="MsoNormal">
              <span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;background:yellow;mso-highlight:yellow">3</span>
              <o:p/>
             </p><p class="MsoNormal">
              <span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif">4</span>
              <o:p/>
             </p><p class="MsoNormal">
              <span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;background:lime;mso-highlight:lime">5</span>
              <o:p/>
             </p><p class="MsoNormal">
              <span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif">&nbsp;</span>
              <o:p/>
             </p>
             <div>
              <div style="border:none;border-top:solid #E1E1E1 1.0pt;padding:3.0pt 0in 0in 0in">
               <p class="MsoNormal">&lt;a name=&quot;<o:p/>
               </p>
              </div><p class="MsoNormal">
               <br>_______________________________________________________________________<o:p/>
               </p>
              </div>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in">
           <p class="MsoNormal">Technical Support.<br>
             <br>
              <br>****************** Internal Use Only ******************<br>To view this request in the CIS View, use the following URL:<br>
           </p>
          </td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
       </table>
       <p class="MsoNormal">
        <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
       </p>
       <div class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center">
        <hr size="3" width="100%" align="center">
       </div>
       <p class="MsoNormal">
        <span style="font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">
         <br>Confidentiality Notice.<br>
       </p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**I need to remove all the elements below the `<p>` tag that has the `<a name="_MailEndCompose">` child. The output should be like the below HTML.**

```html
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 </head>
 <body lang="EN-US">
  <div class="WordSection1">
   <p class="MsoNormal">
    <span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif">This is the document for ER Overview<o:p/>
    </span>
   </p>
   <p class="MsoNormal">
    <span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif">Test 1  <o:p/>
    </span>
   </p>  <p class="MsoNormal">
    <span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif">2<o:p/>
    </span>
   </p>  <p class="MsoNormal">
    <span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;background:yellow;mso-highlight:yellow">3</span>
    <span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif">
     <o:p/>
    </span>
   </p>  <p class="MsoNormal">
    <span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif">4<o:p/>
    </span>
   </p>  <p class="MsoNormal">
    <span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;background:lime;mso-highlight:lime">5</span>
    <span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif">
     <o:p/>
    </span>
   </p>  
   <p class="MsoNormal">
    <a name="_MailEndCompose">
     <span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif">
      <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
     </span>
    </a>
   </p>
     </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Really appreciate your help Gurus. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Siebel programming, but these two templates might help you. They would work for Microsoft's 1.0 XSLT.  Maybe you can leverage.

```
<!-- Identity template -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Suppress everything after the mail end compose. -->
<xsl:template match="*[preceding::p[.//a[@name='_MailEndCompose']]]"/>
```

Comment: Hi Bluewood, Thank you for the suggestion. I am not an expert at XSLT. But its not working. Throws an error "The prefix "xsl" for element "xsl:template" is not bound." when I tested it on http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html. I am still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Hi Krishna,  The only other suggestion I have is to figure out what prefix is being used in Siebel, if any, and use that.  The prefix in my code is defined as xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" and is part of the style sheet instruction...  I hope you get a Siebel programmer to come along and answer this for you.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Bluewood.

Comment: The XSL doesn't work for HTML because it has many non-closing tags.